# Apache Storm: LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE not pushing work to other executors

Tags: apache-storm

I've been playing around with storm topology settings in order to achieve the maximum throughput possible without hitting OutOfMemory errors.

### My Setup:

3-node storm (v1.0.1) cluster. One node is also master, obviously, deployed onto AWS m3.2xlarge instances. There are 12 workers (4 per node):

```
topology.workers: 12
```

and each worker has 4 GB heap space:

```
worker.heap.memory.mb: 4096
```

One of my bolts in particular, let's call it: `HashingBolt` has a parallelism hint of **12**.

This creates 12 executors with one task per executor (because I'm using Flux to configure/deploy).
The stream type *to* `HashingBolt` is `LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE`.

### What I'm expecting:

When clicking on the `HashingBolt` in Storm UI I would expect to see, under the **Executors (All Time)** section, 12 rows - one per executor - and each row ack-ing something.

I would expect storm to first max out the 4 local executors (on the master node, because `LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE` prefers local executors if available), and then revert to shuffle and start to max out the executors on the other two nodes.

### What I'm actually seeing:

Only 4 executors ever do anything. All the others are idle and never ack/emit a single thing. I'm assuming this is because those 4 executors are the local ones, which are being preferred.

Now, if I change the stream type to `SHUFFLE`, then - of course - all executors get working and throughput increases.

### My Questions:

1. Is my surmise correct? Are the 4 executors that are doing something the local ones? Or is that a red herring?
2. Why aren't the other executors being used in `LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE`? Is
   it because the 4 executors that are doing the work aren't being
   max-ed out *enough*?
3. If the 4 local executors *aren't* being max-ed out enough, how do I make it so? Is that to do with stream buffer sizes? Should I decrease/increase etc?
4. If I changed the number of workers to 3 (one per node) would I then start to see work being pushed to remote workers in `LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE` mode?

Any insight or advice is appreciated.

### Addition to Answer Below

In addition to the selected answer below, I believe that selecting SHUFFLE on the bolt with parallelism, and then LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE on following bolts will also ensure that all the workers are kept busy whilst enjoying the potential speed benefits of keeping following work local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I am pretty sure this are the 4 local ones (using Storm UI you can click on a bolt to see where each executor is deployed and which one gets the data and which not -- so you can actually verify this looking at host/port which identifies each worker process)
2. I would assume so. Using Storm UI you can see the "Capacity" column that show you the load for each executor; so you can verify.
3. Why would you want to max them out? What would you gain?
4. If you have only 3 workers, I am actually not sure if all local executors would be considered or not. But even if, the question is again, what would you gain?

Some general comments about this: if you have only 3 nodes, using more workers than nodes does not buy much from a performance point of view. The only performance advantage is that you have less load per internal "dispatcher thread" (see http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2013/06/21/understanding-storm-internal-message-buffers/). As a worker JVM is inherently multi-threaded you can just assign more executor to a single worker -- as long as your machine has enough cores, you will get the speed up you desire.

The main purpose of using more workers per topology than available nodes is actually to get better fault-tolerance. If a worker JVM fails less executors go down. And the reason why a single supervisor can have multiple worker JVM is topology isolation. A single worker JVM will only execute spouts/bolts from a single topology. Thus, if you want to deploy multiple topologies on a single host, you need at least one worker per host per topology.

About local-or-shuffle: if you use local-of-shuffle, why do you worry that not all downstream executors get work assigned? If the local ones can handle the load, you topology runs just fine... and if the could not handle the load, data would get distributed to the others automatically. So I do not understand your concern that not all executors get input data.

Furthermore, if you want to have all executors busy, why not just using **shuffle** instead of **local-or-shuffle**? This guarantees that all executors get the exact same share of the work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! There's just a couple of things that I don't quite understand. Would you only ever use `LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE` in a one-node cluster? Otherwise, what's the point of having 3 nodes if 2 of them are never going to do anything? Re: point 3: I want work to be pushed to the other nodes. When I changed the stream type to `SHUFFLE` the productivity increased nearly 10-fold. Given these figures, I'd say that `LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE` is sort of pointless, as it never really shuffles. Should just use `LOCAL` or `SHUFFLE`...?

Comment: If your load to high, and your local downstream bolts cannot handle it, local-or-shuffle will also consider all other/non-local downstream bolts. The advantage of local forwarding is, that no serialization and network transfer (which can both be quite expensive) is required. Thus, local-or-shuffle can increase your overall throughput. But it depends on your workload.

Comment: What does "cannot handle it" mean, though? Are you saying that it'll only shuffle if the local bolts are being crippled by the load? When would that ever happen, in reality? I'd be interested to know the exact conditions under which the shuffle comes into effect. It's a shame the storm docs are a bit lame in the details area.

Comment: PS: The reason I ask when would that ever happen in reality is because it looks like the stream just gets dialled back. ie: With local or shuffle I was acking between 400 and 1400 in a 10 minute window. With shuffle that goes up to between 11000 and 19000. This is why I would have expected `LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE` to plug away at local until the buffers filled up and then started on the downstream workers.

Comment: I don't know the exact condition, but yes, the basic idea is that if a local downstream bolt "falls back" processing its input, non-local bolts should start to get data, too. But maybe, the new back-pressure feature (introduced in Storm 1.0) makes local-or-shuffle obsolete...